# How to create Bootstrap Popover Close Option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

As you can see in the [jQuery](http://jsfiddle.net/LRCNm/1/), I have used the answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8947749/how-can-i-close-a-twitter-bootstrap-popover-with-a-click-from-anywhere-else-on) to make a Bootstrap Popover disappear on an outside click. Now I am looking to add an "x" in the top right corner that closes the popover on click.

Is there a simple way to create a clickable "x" on the top right corner of the popover that would close the popover when clicked?

HTML:

```
<h3>Live demo</h3>
<div class="bs-docs-example" style="padding-bottom: 24px;">
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-large btn-danger" data-toggle="popover" title="A Title" data-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. right?">Click to toggle popover</a>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
var isVisible = false;
var clickedAway = false;

$('.btn-danger').popover({
    html: true,
    trigger: 'manual'
}).click(function(e) {
    $(this).popover('show');
    clickedAway = false
    isVisible = true
    e.preventDefault()
});

$(document).click(function(e) {
    if (isVisible & clickedAway) {
        $('.btn-danger').popover('hide')
        isVisible = clickedAway = false
    } else {
        clickedAway = true
    }
});
```

Comment: @JorgeCode's code works. I use the first one without adding the close button in the title row. (Can't make a comment on Jorge Code answer because of lack of privilege)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

here is the jquery code:

This one just adds the X button to the right upper corner:

```
            var isVisible = false;
            var clickedAway = false;

            $('.btn-danger').popover({
                    html: true,
                    trigger: 'manual'
                }).click(function(e) {
                    $(this).popover('show');
                    $('.popover-title').append('<button type="button" class="close">&times;</button>');
                    clickedAway = false
                    isVisible = true
                    e.preventDefault()
                });

            $(document).click(function(e) {
              if(isVisible & clickedAway)
              {
                $('.btn-danger').popover('hide')
                isVisible = clickedAway = false
              }
              else
              {
                clickedAway = true
              }
            });
```

And this one closes the popup only when the X button is clicked:

```
            $('.btn-danger').popover({
                    html: true,
                    trigger: 'manual'
                }).click(function(e) {
                    $(this).popover('show');
                    $('.popover-title').append('<button type="button" class="close">&times;</button>');
                    $('.close').click(function(e){
                        $('.btn-danger').popover('hide');
                    });
                    e.preventDefault();
                });
```

Comment: Thank you for this! I +1'ed it! The only problem is that when I add this to my site, clicking on the "x" to close the popover also, for some reason, submits my form. Any idea why that may be?

Comment: Since you technically answered my question, I am going to give you a check also! Still working on the form submit issue.

Comment: hi, the problem isn't in this code. I believe that is somewhere else except if you made this button a submit button...

Comment: Got it solved, it was because of '<button class="close"> instead of something else like '<a class="close">

Comment: Ok i got it but <a> is not a button is a link. Try this: <button type="button" class="close">&times;</button>. Maybe recognizes it like "sumbit" button so maybe if you specify the type="button" will solve your problem.

Comment: Great work on that second easy example!  +1  Exactly the answer I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

I kno this question has been answered already but your post semi-helped me . Stumbled across a simplier way to acomplish this task suppose you have all popovers with the class '.pop', this should solve all your problems

```
$('.pop').on({
  click:function(){
    $('.pop').not(this).popover('hide');
  }
});
```