# Bootstrap tooltips remain visible after navigation in Blazor app

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, blazor, blazor-server-side, jquery-ui-tooltip

I'm new to Blazor and client side web development in general. 
I have the following block of code in my Blazor app:

```
<h1 class="page-title">
    All Offices 
    <a href="@("office-edit")" class="btn btn-primary table-btn" 
        data-toggle="tooltip" 
        data-placement="top" 
        title="Add new office">
        <i class="fas fa-plus"></i>
    </a>
</h1>
```

The tooltip works fine when I hover my mouse over it and move away. However when I click through the link, the tooltip remains visible.
How should I ensure that it disappears?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not blazer issue. It is out of box feature in bootstrap. [See](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/tooltips/) bootstrap example section here, you will see similar behaviour.

You can change this behaviour by writing your own javascript code. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17274130/bootstrap-tooltip-hide-when-another-tooltip-is-click) link will help you to write own javascript.