# Popover open with hover method and hold open with the cursor inside

Tags: jquery, popover, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm working with bootstrap 3, I'm trying to make the popover plugin opened with the hover method, but i can't do it stay opened if the cursor is inside the popover. Any idea? Thanks a lot

This is my code for the popover:

```
$(".info_pop").popover({
    html: true,
    trigger: 'hover',
    title: "Title",
    placement: "top",
    content: 'Example'
});
```

I found the answer [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8947749/how-can-i-close-a-twitter-bootstrap-popover-with-a-click-from-anywhere-else-on). Thank you the same.

Comment: Can you include your CSS, because it's seems to work: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/S8MQB/)

Comment: Yes, work... but i mean when your cursor go inside the popover it should be stay open and not close like in your fiddle

Comment: @fabrizio could you show the code that got this functionality to work? From what I see in the SO post that you linked to, it does not solve the problem. Thanks.