# Cannot access Bootstrap 5 bs.popover data with jQuery

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-5, bootstrap-popover

I was using bootstrap 3 and 4 and wanted to close all popovers when user clicked anywhere else on the page.  I used https://stackoverflow.com/a/21007629/166231 (and 3rd comment) as a guide to implement a solution.

```js
    const hideVisiblePopover = function(): void {
        const visiblePopover = KatApp[ "visiblePopover" ];
        // Just in case the tooltip hasn't been configured
        if ( visiblePopover === undefined || $(visiblePopover).data("bs.popover") === undefined ) return;
    
        // Call this first b/c popover 'hide' event sets visiblePopover = undefined
        if ( that.bootstrapVersion == 3 ) {
            $(visiblePopover).data("bs.popover").inState.click = false
        }
        $(visiblePopover).popover("hide");
    };
```

And my event handlers I set up on the `div` container of all my markup are:

```js
    application.element
        .on("show.bs.popover.RBLe", function() { hideVisiblePopover(); })
        .on("shown.bs.popover.RBLe", function( e ) { 
            KatApp[ "visiblePopover"] = e.target; 
        })
        .on("hide.bs.popover.RBLe", function() { 
            KatApp[ "visiblePopover"] = undefined; 
        });
```

However, with bootstrap 5, my attempt to get the `bs.popover` with this line:

```js
$(visiblePopover).data("bs.popover")
```

Returns undefined.  Is there a different place to look for this now?

Comment: Are you using jQuery with Bootstrap 5?

Comment: Yes.  You have me worried now, that I shouldn't be?

Comment: No, it's [not a problem](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/javascript/#still-want-to-use-jquery-its-possible), was just curious if you were using it now that it's optional

Comment: Yeah, legacy jquery code that hopefully I will not have to re-write.  (Except for the minor problems here and there that I'm having like this)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone that finds this, I solved by using:

```
bootstrap.Popover.getInstance(visiblePopover)
```